# Confused by the Positivity property of an Inner Product when the field is $\mathbb C$ - Attempted Proof

Tags: complex-numbers, inner-products

In my book "*Linear Algebra as an Introduction to Abstract Mathematics*", the **inner product** on vector space $V$ over field $\mathbb F$ is defined as the following map:

$\langle \cdot,\cdot  \rangle : V \times V \to \mathbb F$ where $(u,v) \mapsto \langle u, v \rangle$

Now, given this definition, and the post *here* ([Inner product for vector space over arbitrary field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/216630/inner-product-for-vector-space-over-arbitrary-field?rq=1)) and *here* ([Why are inner product spaces only defined on $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1471153/why-are-inner-product-spaces-only-defined-on-bbb-r-or-bbb-c)), it appears as though the $\mathbb F$ used by the author ***most likely*** refers to either $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$.

The book provides $4$ properties that the inner product must obey...

1. "Linearity in the first slot"
2. "Positivity"
3. "Positive Definiteness"
4. "Conjugate Symmetry"

I am "good to go" with the 1st, 3rd, and 4th property...however, I am sort of stuck understanding how the **positivity property** is implemented when $\mathbb F = \mathbb C$.

The positivity property reads as follows:

**Positivity:** $\langle v,v\rangle \geq 0$ for all $v \in V$.

For $\mathbb F = \mathbb R$, sure...this is something that makes sense. But when the field is set to the complex plane, I am unsure of how to verify this property. Specifically, how does the notion of $\geq$ translate in the context of scalars taken from the complex plane? Is there a *different* conventional form that we adopt for the positivity property when talking about the inner product in the context of $\mathbb F = \mathbb C$?

---

After digging around for a little bit, I came across this post: [Positive definiteness in an inner product over complex numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2972916/positive-definiteness-in-an-inner-product-over-complex-numbers) ,
which (from my interpretation) makes the following claim:

$\langle x,x \rangle = \overline{\langle x,x \rangle} \iff \langle x,x \rangle \in \mathbb R$. If such a claim is true, then I would agree that *even in the context of $V$ over $\mathbb C$, the symbol $\geq$ now makes sense.*

I went to prove this biconditional...**however**, this proof **required me to assert that the only valid fields to define an inner product for are either $\mathbb F = \mathbb R$ or $\mathbb F = \mathbb C$**. And quite frankly, I am unsure if this *really is true* (because I have seen several other posts...not listed...about how inner products can **also** be defined on finite fields).

The proof reads as follows:

**Prove**: if $\langle x,x \rangle \in \mathbb R$, then $\langle x,x \rangle = \overline{\langle x,x \rangle}$

Suppose $a = \langle x,x \rangle \in \mathbb R$. Viewing $a$ in the context of complex numbers, we can say $a = (\lambda, 0)$. By definition of a complex conjugate, $\bar a = (\lambda, -0) = (\lambda,0)$. Therefore, $a = \bar a$ ... $\langle x,x \rangle = \overline{ \langle x,x \rangle }$. Alternatively, you could just say "by Conjugate Symmetry property $\square$ ".

**Prove**: if $\langle x,x \rangle = \overline { \langle x,x \rangle}$ then $\langle x,x \rangle \in \mathbb R$.

Suppose, by contradiction, $\langle x,x \rangle \notin \mathbb R$. Then $\langle x,x \rangle \in \mathbb C$ (because this is the only other option).

Let $z = \langle x,x \rangle = (\lambda, \eta)$. By definition of complex conjugate, $\bar z =  (\lambda, - \eta)$. $z = \bar z$ only if $\eta = -\eta$, but that can only happen if $\eta = 0$, which would mean $z \in \mathbb R$...a contradiction.

**Thus**, $z \notin \mathbb C$, which means $z = \langle x,x \rangle \in \mathbb R$.

So we've proved the biconditional.

**IMPORTANTLY**, this proof required that the only fields I could choose from were either $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$. I have some concerns with this...given the posts I have seen about finite fields also being possible.

Any thoughts on the matter? Thank you!